# Installing an older version of python using anaconda virtual environment on ubuntu?

Tags: python, anaconda

Has older python versions been removed from conda? I am trying to install python 2.7.11, was not able to locate it in the repo.

Comment: Please add more detail.

Comment: Not 100% certain, but I believe Anaconda supports the latest versions of a given branch. So if you wanted Python 2.7, it would probably be 2.7.16 (since Anaconda still supports Python 2.7 currently).